# C# SQL SELECT not working with WHERE = decimal variable

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

This is my code:

```
string query = "SELECT TEKN,KOMMENTAR FROM dbo.JOBBTEKN WHERE JOBBNR = " + jobId + ".00";
SqlDataReader reader = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConn).ExecuteReader();
```

This is my data:

[image: Data]

I want to fetch multiple rows with the exact `JOBBNR`, but this returns nothing.

EDIT:
The query was working, it was just me being stupid and not searching in the right table. Sorry for wasting anyones time trying to help.

Comment: Why even consider decimals for jobbnr? What's wrong with good old integer?

Comment: @jarlh It's not my database, I'm making my own client for bad software my company bought!

Comment: can you check the `JOBBNBR` data type, also jobId type in C# ?

Comment: @Jacky It's a decimal in SQL and I cast it as an integer in c# when I'm displaying it for the user.

Answer (score 3):

Include the `jobId` in single quotes. Modify your query to following:

```
"SELECT TEKN,KOMMENTAR FROM dbo.JOBBTEKN WHERE JOBBNR = '" + jobId + ".00'"
```

Observe the single quote around `jobId`.

---

Looking at the comments, I suspect the datatype of `JOBBNR` is `float`; NOT `decimel`. `float` datatype internally contains multiple precision, so when you try to match them in `WHERE =` clause, you may not get result due to mismatched precision.

There are multiple ways to handle this problem. Try **something like** following:

```
WHERE JOBBNR BETWEEN 1200.00 AND 1200.01
```

OR

```
"WHERE JOBBNR BETWEEN '" + jobId + ".00' AND '" + jobId + ".01'"
```

Comment: @AmitJoshi I'm so sorry guys, I was searching in the wrong table... This database is so confusing! Thanks for the help anyways!